# How do you search for embedded documents with an OR statement in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I've tried a few ways to try to do this but none of them work:

```
User.where(name:"Jon Sparks").first.purchased_items.where
          ('(month = 5 AND year = 2012) OR (month = 6 AND year = 2012)')

User.where(name:"Jon Sparks").first.purchased_items.any_of
          ({:month => 5, :year => 2012}, {:month => 6, :year => 2012})
```

What I want to do is pull all `purchased_items` embedded documents in 5/2012 or 6/2012.

Comment: Have you tried? : `User.where(name:"Jon Sparks").first.purchased_items.where(:$and => {:year => 2012}, :$or => {:month => [5,6]})`

Comment: I get the following error: `undefined method 'gsub' for :year:Symbol`

Comment: I think you are over thinking the `OR` part of your condition. It is really an `IN`. I am not an expert at Mongo, so I will watch this, but I would try `User.where(name:"Jon Sparks").first.purchased_items.where(:year => 2012, :month => [5,6]})` or `User.where(name:"Jon Sparks").first.purchased_items.where('year = 2012 AND month IN (5,6)')`

Comment: Just tried that as well and got 0 results. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Sorry, could't help. I am just starting on a MongoDB project, so will watch this. Thanks for trying with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your query

```
User.where(:name => "JohnSparks").first.purchased_items.where(:year => 2012, :month.in => [5,6])
```